# Togglable animated vertical nav-bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So i have a sliding vertical nav-bar. I would like to be able to press my toggle button but it to not disappear and just stay at the top of the page instead of the whole thing just disappearing.I want everything to go other than  the toggle. Thanks

Here is a JSfiddle link: 
https://jsfiddle.net/fraserdale/31da97uc/  
Thanks for any help

```
<body>
<div class="sidenav slideTogglebox">
    <div class="toggle change" onclick="myFunction(this)" id="slideToggle">
        <div class="bar1 animated fadeIn"></div>
        <div class="bar2 "></div>
        <div class="bar3 animated fadeIn"></div>
    </div>
  <ul class="sidebar-inner " id="modes"> 
    <li class="gamemode fa fa-3x fa-dot-circle-o active animated fadeIn"><a href="#"></a></li>
    <li class="gamemode fa fa-3x fa-pie-chart animated fadeIn"><a href="#"></a></li>
    <li class="gamemode fa fa-3x fa-delicious animated fadeIn"><a href="#"></a></li>
    <li class="gamemode fa fa-3x fa-line-chart animated fadeIn"><a href="#"></a></li>
    <li class="gamemode fa fa-3x fa-braille animated fadeIn"><a href="#"></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<p class="credit animated fadeIn">Memes Beta UI</p>


<script>
function myFunction(x) {
x.classList.toggle("change");
var x = document.getElementById('modes');
if (x.style.display === 'none') {
    x.style.display = 'block'
} else {
    x.style.display = 'none';
}

</script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $("#slideToggle").click(function () {
     $('.slideTogglebox').slideToggle();
 });
 </script>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```js
$("#slideToggle").click(function(e) {
 $(this).toggleClass('change');
  var $modes = $("#modes"),
      $sidenav = $('.sidenav'),
      timer = 1000;
  if ($(this).hasClass('change')) {
    $sidenav.animate({
      height: '100vh'
    }, timer)
  } else {
    $modes.css('position','absolute');
    var autoHeight = $('.sidenav').css('height', 'auto').height();
    $sidenav.css('height', '100vh');
    $modes.css('position','relative');
    $sidenav.animate({
      height: autoHeight
    }, timer)
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #23272B;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  outline: none;
}

.credit {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif
}

.sidenav {
  overflow: auto;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 200;
  background-color: #16191C;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  width: 125px;
  height: 100vh;
  color: #e1ffff;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

* {
  transition: all 500ms ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-out;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: open sans, sans-serif;
}

.sidebar-inner {
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  flex: 1 0 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

ul .gamemode:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: #3B50D4;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

li {
  transition: all 500ms ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-out;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.active {
  background-color: #3B50D4;
}

.gamemode {
  /*border: 1px solid white;*/
  width: 65px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15%;
  /*display: block;*/
}

.toggle {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 25%;
  position: relative;
  background: #16191C;
  z-index: 1;
}

.bar1,
.bar2,
.bar3 {
  width: 45px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #333;
  margin: 6px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}


/* Rotate first bar */

.change .bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
}


/* Fade out the second bar */

.change .bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
}


/* Rotate last bar */

.change .bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Memes</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/9d0e231cc7.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="sidenav slideTogglebox">
      <div class="toggle change" id="slideToggle">
        <div class="bar1 animated fadeIn"></div>
        <div class="bar2 "></div>
        <div class="bar3 animated fadeIn"></div>
      </div>
      <ul class="sidebar-inner " id="modes">
        <li class="gamemode fa fa-3x fa-dot-circle-o active animated fadeIn">
          <a href="#"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="gamemode fa fa-3x fa-pie-chart animated fadeIn">
          <a href="#"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="gamemode fa fa-3x fa-delicious animated fadeIn">
          <a href="#"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="gamemode fa fa-3x fa-line-chart animated fadeIn">
          <a href="#"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="gamemode fa fa-3x fa-braille animated fadeIn">
          <a href="#"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <p class="credit animated fadeIn">Memes Beta UI</p>

  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a class on toggle.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/blecaf/y9qnkbmr/1/)**

```
$("#slideToggle").click(function() {
  $(".sidebar-inner ").toggleClass("slide-menu");
});
```